# Execute Shell Script on remote host using SSH

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and existing job uses Execute Shell script on the remote host using SSH in the Build. In the SSH Site, there is a lot of username@ip in the drop-down box so that the developer can select the SSH site and build.

Now, my requirement is to add an IP to the SSH Site. I am not authorized to install plugins. How to add an IP to the SSH Site to the existing set of IP's?

Comment: SSH Site? Do you mean Jenkins UI? By adding IP do you mean also add a node?

Answer (score 0):

new ssh sites are added from jenkins global configuration under ssh hosts. 
Manage Jenkins--> SSH hosts --> Add new site

Hope this answers your questions

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't have access to Manage Jenkins. I just have a folder and many jobs underneath it.

Comment: In this case you need to contact the admin to add ssh sites.

Comment: thanks, the solution worked. I need to get permission for SSH site plugin and added the username, port and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can add SSH remote in latest Jenkins version in this way
Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> SSH remote hosts -> Add